# Copy from csv to xls

Tags: vba

Ihave constantly problem with copying data from csv to xls. Data in csv ar spread in a few columns, but after copying them with vba code and pasting into xls columns are concatenated with `;` and float numbers are devide into separate columns because floats in csv contain `,` as decimal separator.

Comment: Can you please provide a code snippet?

Comment: I'm copying data using temporal array

Comment: still not enough information.

Comment: You can simply open a .csv in Excel, then save as xlsx. Why not just do that? Also, you can add a new line to the top of the .csv file with the text `"sep=;"` (and nothiung else) to make Excel realize that the separator in your file is a `;` (semicolon).

Comment: @vacip, I didn't know that. Cool!